# Junit how to achieve100% coverage for Model class

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have a model class:

```
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(updatable = true, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Email(message = "Enter a valid email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "First name cannot be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "First name character must be more than 3!")
    private String firstName;
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Last name character must be more than 3!")
    private String lastName;

    @Range(min = 21, max = 55, message = "Age must be between 21 and 55")
    private int age;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Double accBalance;

    @NotNull(message = "Gender cannot be empty")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull(message = "Country cannot be empty")
    private String country;

    @JsonProperty("Job Scope")
    private String designation;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date birthDate;
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
class EmployeeTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testObjectMethod() {
        Employee object = new Employee();
        object.equals(new Employee());
        object.hashCode();
        object.toString();
    }
    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        Employee object = new Employee();
        object.equals(Employee.builder().build());
    }
}
```

And this is my coverage. Basically it only covers 73.8%. What other tests do I need to do to achieve 100%? As this covers quite a lot and doesn't need much of thinking, I would like to target 100%. Appreciate any help or pointers.

[coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxmHH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sonar will complain about your test class as there must be at least one assertion and public modifier should be removed. You can modify your code as below to be sonar complainat

```
class EmployeeTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testObjectMethod() {
        Employee object = new Employee();
        object.equals(new Employee());
        object.hashCode();
        object.toString();
        assertNotNull(object.toString());
    }
    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        Employee object = new Employee();
        object.equals(Employee.builder().build());
        assertNotNull(object.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you cover all possible paths of your methods. For example, `equals(Object o)` is usually implemented in such a way that it:

- checks for identity (`o == this`)
- checks if o is an instance of the class
- checks if members are equal
- contains null checks

My tests for `equals` usually look like this:

```
@Test
public void testEquals() {
    Employee object = new Employee();
    assertTrue(object.equals(object))
    assertTrue(object.equals(new Employee());
    assertFalse(object.equals(null));
    assertFalse(object.equals(new Object()));
    ...
}
```

Your IDE may be able to help you findomg paths in your code which are not covered by unit test.